# Video Hover Effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a video hover effect on an image which is when on mouse over it should pop up a video just like the one in this [website](http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/.)

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for the last couple of months.

Does anyone know how to do it?

This is actually an image hover effect which i have managed to get.So instead of the image popping up, is there any way for a video to pop up just like the image?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {


    $('div.thumbnail-item').mouseenter(function(e) {


        x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;


        $(this).css('z-index','15')
        .children("div.tooltip")
        .css({'top': y + 10,'left': x + 20,'display':'block'});

    }).mousemove(function(e) {


        x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;


    $(this).children("div.tooltip").css({'top': y + 10,'left': x + 20});

    }).mouseleave(function() {


        $(this).css('z-index','1')
        .children("div.tooltip")
        .animate({"opacity": "hide"}, "fast");
    });

});


</script>
<style>

    .thumbnail-item { 

position: relative; 
float: left;  
margin: 0px 5px; 
     }

      .thumbnail-item a { 
display: block; 
      }

     .thumbnail-item img.thumbnail {
border:3px solid #ccc;  
     }

       .tooltip { 

display: none; 

position: absolute; 

padding: 8px 0 0 8px; 
       }

.tooltip span.overlay { 

    background: url(images/overlay.png) no-repeat; 

    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    display: block; 
    width: 350px; 
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
   </head>
    <body>



<div class="thumbnail-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Capture1.jpg" class="thumbnail"/></a>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <img src="images/2 Davis Road.jpg" alt="" width="330" height="185" />
        <span class="overlay"></span>
    </div> 
</div> 

<div class="thumbnail-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Capture2.jpg" class="thumbnail"/></a>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <img src="images/Camberwell Town Hall, Roof Restoration.jpg" alt="" width="330" height="185" />
        <span class="overlay"></span>
    </div> 
</div> 

<div class="thumbnail-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Capture3.jpg" class="thumbnail"/></a>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <img src="images/Children.jpg" alt="" width="330" height="185" />
        <span class="overlay"></span>
    </div> 
</div>      

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: You've spent a couple of months trying?  Show what you tried.  If I spend five minutes looking at the source from that page, I can easily find how they handle the mouseover, give it content, and what that content is.

Comment: @paddy:i have added the code that i have.Please take a look at it

Comment: I *HATE* when websites do that. I accidentally moved my mouse over something, a video popped up and locked up my netbook. I kept trying to close it but the video and all the other javascript on the page made things too slow and I couldn't even use my computer.

Comment: This might help http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Comment: You could always create a new page with the video, and link to it like a normal pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) with event listeners ([`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)) to insert a video element in a tooltip. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) provide great tooltips which you can use on your websites.

Here's an example of the code with jQuery:

```
$(".video").on("mouseenter", function(){
    var video = "<video></video>"; // remember to add the src attribute, etc...

    // code for displaying tooltip

    $(".tooltip").append(video); // assuming tooltip has class of .tooltip

    $(this).on("mouseleave", function(){
        // code here for hiding the tooltip when the hover stops
    }
})
```